# How does auto-pickup work?

Tags: borderlands-2

The feature that auto-picks up money and ammo is neat, but seems very inconsistent; sometimes I auto-pick up money and ammo that I need, sometimes I have to manually pick items up. I'm talking about the feature that collects without a button press, not the long-press action that picks up all "minor loot" in the area.

What's the trick? Are enemy-drops auto-collected and container loot not picked up? I think I've been observing that but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I really wish they would auto-pickup out of containers as well.

Comment: The auto-pickup is pretty buggy really. If you are on any sort of slope, you can't auto-pickup anything that's higher or lower than you on the slope. Also stuff sometimes lands under the ground or other objects (I see this all the time when farming The Warrior), and you have to manually pick that up too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The auto pickup system specifically only picks up ammunition and money.

In co-operative mode you share ammunition so you never have to feel like you are stealing ammo from someone.

A possible explanation for the issues you're experiencing could relate to similar behaviour from the original Borderlands in that latency could allow you to pass an item without picking it up.

[You're not the only one who has experienced this behaviour](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/borderlands-2-impressions-the-review-was-lacking.452671091/), several gamers are reporting the symptoms of ammunition and gold not being automatically picked up.

Comment: You share ammo in coop now? That's an awesome change from the first game

Comment: I have not experienced ammo being shared between players in coop

Comment: Somebody else asked this particular question directly @OrigamiRobot - I have [posted an answer to it here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85043/27134) based on the information I am able to find there is no obvious indicator that ammunition is shared

Comment: @OrigamiRobot ammo is definitely shared (i.e. everyone gets it, not divided between players). Use up your ammo from a common gun you rarely use, say shotgun, then don't pick up ammo for a while in co-op and you'll find it restocked as others pick it up for you.

Answer (score 6):

Auto-pickup system only works on items (ammo and money) droped from monsters/destroyable objects (barrels,gas tanks,etc.).

All items from chests and containers can only be manually picked up.