# How is money shared in co-op?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am inclined to think that money is somehow shared in co-op, but what is exact formula?  Do all players get the full amount found, or is the amount found divided equally - or some other formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All money, ammo and eridian is shared equally amongst co-op players.

See [How is ammo shared when playing co-op?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84975/how-is-ammo-shared-when-playing-co-op)

Comment: Others get half the ammo.