# Is there a way to make Auto-Pickup work with lockers/containers?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been getting sick of having to constantly press "E" to pickup items/loot in Borderlands 2 and then I found out about "Auto-Pickup". The big downside that I've heard about is the inability for "Auto-Pickup" to get items from crates.

> The auto pickup system specifically **only picks up** ammunition and money. - [Kalina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84922/47129)

> All items from chests and containers can only be manually picked up. - [ChrisHateZ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84926/47129)

So my question is: Is there anyway for me to be able to pickup items from lockers/containers/etc. automatically?

It isn't that big of a deal, but when there are a lot of lockers/containers/etc. around it gets to be a little annoying. Also I am aware of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/how-does-auto-pickup-work), but I think my question is unique enough to justify it.

Comment: Well, there's no setting for this anywhere, even in the cfg files to my knowledge. So any way would require a mod for sure. Whether such a mod exists I have no idea

Comment: I don't know of any way to automatically pick up anything other than money or ammo. One reason why it's not possible, might be because money and ammo do not waste space in your inventory, unlike weapons or other items.

Comment: @Nolonar Well the weapons thing makes sense, because you wouldn't want the game swapping out your current weapon without you having a  choice.

Comment: @BenBrocka Well it's not that big of a deal, but I'd like the game to be able to open lockers/containers and pickup money/ammo/health.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Autopickup only works for ammo and money dropped from killed enemies/destroyed containers.

You need manually open every container, but then you can pickup all ammo and money near you by holding down USE key on money or ammo item.